# How to use $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ method to prove that the function $f(x)$ is an everywhere discontinuous function?

Tags: calculus, functions

> $f(x)=\begin{cases}
> 1, & \text {if x is rational}\\
> 0, & \text {if x is irrational}
> \end{cases}$

How to use $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ method to prove that the function $f(x)$ is an everywhere discontinuous function?

I approached the problem using 'Proof by Contradiction'...but i couldn't work it out.If anyone could please help me  approach these type of problems correctly it would be very helpful indeed!

Thanking you in advance!

Comment: Start by assuming that there's some point at which $f$ is continuous. Apply the definition of continuity (write it down), then look again at the function, and see what you can do to create a contradiction.

Comment: I'm certain this is a duplicate. That said, consider any $0<\varepsilon<1.$

Comment: @Cameron Buie,can you kindly post the link of the original one.

Comment: It's epsilon ***hyphen*** delta, not epsilon ***minus*** delta. So type `$\varepsilon$-$\delta$`, not `$\varepsilon-\delta$`.